# closed questions on front page?

Tags: discussion

I think if a question has 4 downvotes it won't show on the front page.

Should this not be the same for **closed** questions like this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3579)?

Comment: Is this still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not currently that way; I'm not sure if that's ever been brought up before. You can post this on the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) as a feature request and see what they say